# How to run an SQL code on a very large CSV file (4 million+ records) without needing to open it

Tags: sql, excel, csv, large-files

I have a very large file of 4 million+ records that I want to run an sql query on. However, when I open the file it will only return 1 million contacts and not load the rest. Is there a way for me to run my query without opening the file so I do not lose any records? PS I am using a Macbook so some functions and add ins are not available for me.

Comment: Running it through Excel will not work.  You will want to run it through an actual data base.

Comment: @ScottCraner a bit of a newbie do you have any resources on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/) to ingest a multi-million lines of CSV and run SQL commands with your macbook

Here is the command to load the file

```
CREATE TABLE steam AS SELECT * from read_csv_auto('bigfile.csv');
```

you can even import/load part of it by adding a 'WHERE' command to you SQL query